# Database design for project-based roles

Tags: database, postgresql, relational-database

Let's assume I have a project with the following entities:

- User
- Project

So, a ***User*** is related to a ***Project*** via a Many-to-Many relationship. So let's assume the join table is called ***user_projects*** which contains both the ***user_id*** and the ***project_id***.

So, the problem is that a user has different access rights (permissions) based on their role (so I need to somehow implement the ***Role*** entity into my database schema) in the project, and I'm a little confused as to how I would implement this in my database. Please bear in mind that a user is not bound to a single role during registration, the role is decided when a project gets created.

My train of thought was the following. I guess both ***Users*** and ***Projects*** would be related to the ***Role*** as a Many-to-Many relation, is that correct? So both would need their own join table, something like ***user_roles*** and ***project_roles***. But this seems a little odd to me, and could be handled more elegantly somehow, I imagine.

Any advice would be much appreciated, apologies if the answer is blatantly obvious, Im new to database design.

Many thanks!

Comment: So the same user could be in different Roles on different Projects? But only one Role for each Project they're assigned to? Then `Role` is a non-key field on the `user-projects` bridge table.

Comment: Yes exactly, the user can have different roles, depending on the project they are on, but only one role per project for a user. Sorry if im being slow, so does that mean the user_projects table should have a role_id field, meaning the bridge table will be related to roles in a One-to-Many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the `user_projects` table that you have:

```
CREATE TABLE roles (
   role_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   role_description text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_projects (
   user_id bigint REFERENCES users NOT NULL,
   project_id bigint REFERENCES projects NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (project_id, user_id),
   role_id bigint REFERENCES roles  NOT NULL
);
```

Then every entry in `user_projects` does not only relate a user and a project, but also assigns a role in the project.