# ORM: Is it possible to resolve a foreign key to two different relationships?

Tags: spring, database, hibernate, orm, typeorm

## The problem

I am going to provide a simple example which will describe the problem I am currently facing in a larger project.

- An event has n participants
- These participants can have different roles (e.g. Visitor, EventService)
- It is not possible for a participant to attend the same event in two different roles

On the database level I want to create two tables: Event and Participant.
Event is connected with Participant in a 1-n relation.

On the application level I want to separate these two relationships depending on their type.
The event class holds a list of visitors and a list of eventService (both of type Participant).

## Question

- Is it possible to achieve this using an ORM abstraction (e.g. Spring-Hibernate or TypeORM)?
- Is this a good approach in general (if not, are there better options without duplicating the table)?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it is possible :) You can create object hierarchy that will map to a single table in db. For example in spring jpa + lombok:

```
    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    public  class Person{
        @Id @GeneratedValue @Getter
        private long id;
    }

    @Entity
    @DiscriminatorValue("VST")
    public class Visitor extends Person{
    }

    @Entity
    @DiscriminatorValue("ES")
    public class EventService extends Person{
    }

    @Entity
    public class Event{
        @Id @GeneratedValue @Getter
        private long id;
        @OneToMany
        private List<Visitor> visitorList;
        @OneToMany
        private List<EventService> eventServiceList;
    }
```

*Disclaimer: I've not tested this example, so there might be some mistakes:)*

2. There are a lot of factors to take into account and lot of "personal tastes". This approach is not inherently good or bad.  When valuing it's worth to take into account db performance and extensibility of schema.

Comment: Thanks for the already very helpful answer. This was exactly what I was looking for concerning the ORM abstraction. Can you elaborate on 2) a bit and provide another approach that you might use / have seen in practice so I can then compare it to my original idea? One very simple approach that comes to mind is duplicating the tables but as you said "Extensibility of schema" is a major downside in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I was away for weekend. As for other approaches: if you want to use inheritance to model your business objects then your orm mappings are just 3: SINGLE_TABLE, TABLE_PER_CLASS, JOINED. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance for a good roundup of good/bad sides of each. 

Another road you can take is using composition, i.e. Visitor and EService classes have a field of Person class and those three have no inheritance relations between themselves. Possible use case is when one person is guest in one event and a service man in other.